# preg_match_all not matching all possibilities

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to retrieve **all** matches however I am only receiving one

Here  is my string

```
$html = '<p> This is my Home Page.</p><p><span style="line-height: 1.42857;">{{ type="slider" }} </span></p><p> </p>';
```

If you see string contain  `{{ type="slider" }}`  , now if i write this string only once i am getting my expected result, 
but if i write it multiple times in html sting like  `{{ type="slider" }}`  `{{ type="banned" }}` `{{ type="testimonial" }}`

```
$html = '<p> This is my Home Page.</p><p><span style="line-height: 1.42857;">{{ type="slider" }} {{ type="banner" }} {{ type="testimonial" }}  </span></p><p> </p>';
```

and try to get the values within my string `{{ type=" ???? " }}` it shows  weird result

I am using this below code .

```
preg_match_all('/{{ type=\"(.+)\" }}/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: ". $val[0] . "<br/>";
    echo "My Value" . $val[1] . "<br/>"; 
}
```

Current Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ type="slider" }} {{ type="banner" }} {{ type="testimonial" }}
            [1] => slider" }} {{ type="banner" }} {{ type="testimonial
        )

)
matched: {{ type="slider" }} {{ type="banner" }} {{ type="testimonial" }}
My Value : slider" }} {{ type="banner" }} {{ type="testimonial
```

I am expecting result in array with the values written between `{{ type="` and `" }}`

with `{{ type="slider" }}` only i am getting this result which is perfect.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ type="slider" }}
            [1] => slider
        )

)
matched: {{ type="slider" }}
My Value : slider
```

Any idea ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: try `preg_match_all('/{{ type=\"(.+?)\" }}/mi', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your regex match non-greedy by adding either a `?` :

```
preg_match_all('/{{ type=\"(.+?)\" }}/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

or the `U` modifier:

```
preg_match_all('/{{ type=\"(.+)\" }}/U', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286071/preg-match-all-find-match-multiple-stings-and-get-the-values-written-in-double-q  Can you ans this question ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently getting is pretty normal, since by default your regexp is greedy, i.e. `/{{ type="(.+)"}} /` looks for the longest string beginning with `{{ type="` and ending with `}}`.

Another answer here suggests you to add a "not-greedy" quantifier `?` and it'll work but it's not the best solution (because it'll need more work from the regex engine).

Instead you'd better to merely replace `(.+)` by `([^"]+)` in your regexp.

Comment: My regex abilities suck, so I'm just gonna upvote your answer :)

Comment: Okay  but this way i can not get the value written in in type=" ".

Comment: @PunitGajjar Probably because you tried my first version, where I'd forgotten the capturing parenthesis! Look at the current version.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your fair attitude!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286071/preg-match-all-find-match-multiple-stings-and-get-the-values-written-in-double-q  can you solve this  ?