# preg_match_all match multiple strings and get the values written in double quotes

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Recently [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284949/preg-match-all-not-matching-all-possibilities) regarding `preg_match_all` with php,  and i got the perfect solution as expected but now I have some different scenario

**here is my string :**

```
$html = '<p> This is my Home Page.</p><p><span style="line-height: 1.42857;">
        {{ type="slider" pagename="slider-1" }} 
        {{ type="banner"  pagename="banner-1" }} 
        {{ type="testimonial"  pagename="testimonial-1" }}
        </span></p><p> </p>';
```

**My Code :**

```
preg_match_all('/{{ type="(.+?)" }}/', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($matches);

foreach ($matches as  $val) {

    echo $val[1];
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

**Result i am getting :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ type="slider" pagename="slider-1" }}
            [1] => slider" pagename="slider-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ type="banner"  pagename="banner-1" }}
            [1] => banner"  pagename="banner-1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{ type="testimonial"  pagename="testimonial-1" }}
            [1] => testimonial"  pagename="testimonial-1
        )

)
slider" pagename="slider-1
banner"  pagename="banner-1
testimonial"  pagename="testimonial-1
```

How can i get the values for `slider` and `pagename` variable written in `{{` and `}}` in the string  ?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.regex101.com for testing? it works wonders and will probably educate you on how to add a second capturing group

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
/{{ type=\"(.+)\"\s+pagename=\"(.+)\" }}/i
```

In action: https://regex101.com/r/tX9vD3/1

Comment: I think you need "m" the modifier

Comment: @Mike what is that  ?

Comment: @Zanderwar Can you please create a chatroom  for our discussion ?

Comment: It's because you have varying amounts of spaces between `"` and `pagename`.

Comment: Thanks @Mike thought I lost my bearings there

Comment: Try `{{ type="(.*)"[\s]+pagename="(.*)" }}`. Not sure if you have to add `g` modifier or if it's implied like `m` is.